# Is it possible to make multiple camera solvers for motion tracking in one project?

Tags: camera, video, tracking

I have a video with many switching angles on one object. Sometimes the object should be outside the camera view. I need to have at least 5 camera trackings to properly insert this object into the video.

I've tried many ways to do that, but it doesn't work in any, it always breaks on the fact that it looks like Blender has motion tracking and a camera solver as a single global instance, **even between the scenes**, rendering making several cameras having separate solvers or at least one camera having multiple seem impossible.
Please, help with that, is there any possible workaround?

Important: making multiple projects is highly undesirable, the object has its own animation and effects, and copying that over 5 different projects on every slight change would be pretty unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I haven't found an exactly elegant solution, but this one works kind of well.

1. Copy your project
2. Open it
3. Make all the motion tracking for one of the camera angles you need
4. Select your camera you've assigned motion tracking to
5. Export it as alembic .abc, make sure you are exporting only the selected object
6. Import the exported alembic file back to the original project
7. Repeat for every camera angle on your scene

This will keep a camera motion on the exported cameras without the need to use camera solver
After that you will just need to switch cameras on every angle and will have all the motions set in one single project